# Turtlebot not spawning in Gazebo

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I just installed ros kinetic, gazebo and turtlebot in Ubuntu 16.04. when i run

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

in terminal gazebo opens with the standard obstacles but there is no bot.

I installed gazebo with apt-get.

this is the error i get i terminal:

```
[spawn_turtlebot_model-4] process has died [pid 11263, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base __name:=spawn_turtlebot_model __log:=/home/andreas/.ros/log/d859e7e6-659c-11e7-bff4-a402b924af68/spawn_turtlebot_model-4.log].
log file: /home/andreas/.ros/log/d859e7e6-659c-11e7-bff4-a402b924af68/spawn_turtlebot_model-4*.log
```

Any help appreciated!

---

Edit: This is what terminal is showing when i run `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch`.

Still no bot showing:

```
andreas@andreas-N501VW:~$ roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch 
... logging to /home/andreas/.ros/log/10d4ccd2-6677-11e7-bff4-a402b924af68/roslaunch-andreas-N501VW-30220.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
deprecated: xacro tags should be prepended with 'xacro' xml namespace.
Use the following script to fix incorrect usage:
        find . -iname "*.xacro" | xargs sed -i 's#<\([/]\?\)\(if\|unless\|include\|arg\|property\|macro\|insert_block\)#<\1xacro:\2#g'
when processing file: /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro

xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://andreas-N501VW:35697/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    spawn_urdf (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [30242]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [30247]
process[spawn_urdf-3]: started with pid [30252]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model", line 32, in <module>
    import tf.transformations as tft
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _tf import *
ImportError: /home/andreas/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/_tf.so)
[ INFO] [1499808994.861676790]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1499808994.862201127]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[spawn_urdf-3] process has died [pid 30252, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -urdf -model turtlebot3_burger -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.0 -param robot_description __name:=spawn_urdf __log:=/home/andreas/.ros/log/10d4ccd2-6677-11e7-bff4-a402b924af68/spawn_urdf-3.log].
log file: /home/andreas/.ros/log/10d4ccd2-6677-11e7-bff4-a402b924af68/spawn_urdf-3*.log
[ INFO] [1499808995.548652766, 0.023000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1499808995.631034578, 0.102000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265934/turtlebot-not-spawning-in-gazebo/) by [AndreasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/31096/andreasg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-07-10**:
Please provide more information on how to reproduce your problem. As well as the full console logs of what you're doing, not just the one line error. http://wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [AndreasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/31096/andreasg/) on 2017-07-11**:
The problem is that i dont find a bot when i run "roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch" in terminal. Gazebo opens and there are objects like cylinder, jersy barrier, bookshelf an so on showing in the map/world. This happens everytime I run the command. Is it not supposed to show up?

**Comment by [AndreasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/31096/andreasg/) on 2017-07-11**:
And where do I find that log?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-12**:
@AndreasG: please don't pose answers unless you are answering your own question. For everything else, either use comments (to interact with posters of specific answers) or update your original question text. Use the *edit* button/link for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution. There was a problem with having Anaconda2 installed. Since I dont need Anaconda I deleted it along with the content of catkin_ws. I ran the installation steps again and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [AndreasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/31096/andreasg/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0